# Install 64-bit JDK versions with Ninite

Tags: java, jdk, ninite

I'm attempting to build a Ninite installer/updater for my own use and I've found it fantastic.

However, as part of the profile, I would like to include the installation of multiple versions of the 64-bit JDK (6, 7 and 8) as I do a lot of Java programming in my spare time.

Unfortunately, while I can see that Ninite supports multiple JDK versions ([reference](https://ninite.com/applist/pro.html)), I cannot find a way to include them in the installer.

I've attempted manually creating a URL like so: `https://ninite.com/jdk6-jdk7-jdk8` and this works wonders for the 32-bit versions of the JDK, but I cannot find seem to find the URL parameters for the 64-bit versions.

I have tried varying combinations of:
`"jdkx64", "jdkx647", "jdk%20x64", "jdk%20x64%207"` and `"jdk64"`, to no avail.

**Does anyone else familiar with Ninite know how to address the 64-bit versions of the JDK?**

Comment: I know the pro version has a method for this.  No idea how to form a URL to get this...

Comment: I've submitted a feedback form asking about this issue and I will post their response as soon as I hear back from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from Ninite.

The appropriate URL parameter for the 64-bit JDK is `https://ninite.com/jdkx`.

Unfortunately, I was not able to discover the URL parameters for specific 64-bit versions.

Comment: I just tried https://ninite.com/jdkx7/ and it works for version 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

https://ninite.com/java8-javax8-jdk8-jdkx8-java7-javax7-jdk7-jdkx7-java6-javax6-jdk6-jdkx/
will install the latest JREs and JDKs of versions 6 to 8, both in 32 & in 64 bit.